# 2009 Honda Accord door locks only work with key fob - not door power buttons

Tags: honda, accord, power, locks

Having a strange issue with my 2009 Accord.  The door locks just stopped working when using the buttons on any of the doors.  They lock and unlock just fine using the remote key fob buttons.  I hear no clicking or any noise when I try to use the buttons on the doors.  Anyone have this issue?  I can only find posts where the key fob stops working...  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You’re probably going to have to use a scantool like the HDS to talk to the MICU and confirm the master window switch is sending the unlock/lock command. Afaik the driver master switch acts as a hub for the other lock switch using a serial data line. The master switch sends a command over the can line to the micu which then activates the lock/unlock relays. The remote system is a different module that sends commands to the micu.

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem? I’m seeing the same thing on my 2008 accord.